# Splash Image for android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I made a splash image to show at the start of my activity..
The image show perfectly.But the problem is when i call this

```
public class SplashImageActivity extends Activity {
    protected boolean active = true;
    protected int splashTime = 5000; // time to display the splash screen in ms

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(active && (waited < splashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(active) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashImageActivity.this,Myapps.class));
                    finish();
                    //startActivity(new Intent("com.splash.com.MyApps"));
                    //startActivity( new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Myapps.class));
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            active = false;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

go for next activity the `stop()` does not work. And it does not go to this activity. I add all activity in manifest. The `stop()` shows in code like this

[image]

what's the problem?

Comment: did u try putting startActivity() before finish()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to call stop() and call finish() after starting activity

```
finally 
{

    startActivity(new Intent(currentclass.this,nextActivity.class);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use thread to show the Splash screen, and it works for me:

```
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(4000);
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){                   
            }
            finish();

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            interrupt();
        }

    }; 
    mSplashThread.start();        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code..

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                        startActivity( new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Exercise.class));
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t2.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing it is not onStop of Activity so looks you are calling stop function of thread which is `Deprecated` that's why you are getting the strike line so use other way to stop the thread of use better way to implement the splash ........

as looks you try some thing like this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App)

Answer (score 0):

No need to call stop() just call finish() after starting activity

```
finally {
startActivity(new Intent(currentclass.this,nextActivity.class);
finish();
}
```

You can also use handler an postdelayed() to make a splash screen like below

```
 public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity{

        private Handler handler;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

            final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                       Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                       finish();

                }
            };
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);


        }

    }
```

You will show your splash screen for 5 seconds and then move to next Activity

Comment: Hei i tried your code.The image come,but not go to the next activity

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha what error you get for me it works, i grab it for you from one of my app src

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha have you added your secon activity declaration in the manifest?

Comment: i declard it.but still force closed

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha can you post logcat trace?