# Show ImageView for second and then Hide with Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-imageview

I need to show ImageView for second and then Hide using Thread when I clicked in the menuInflater.

For example:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.txt1:
        handler = new Handler (this);
                    Worker w = new Worker (handler);
                   Thread t = new Thread (w);
                   t.start();
         return true;
```

---

Do you mean like this?

```
 protected int [] imgIds = {
        R.id.img_1,R.id.img_2,R.id.img_3,R.id.img_4,R.id.img_5,R.id.img_6,
        R.id.img_7,R.id.img_8,R.id.img_9,R.id.img_10,R.id.img_11,R.id.img_12,
};

    public class Worker implements Runnable{

private Handler h;

public Worker (Handler h)
{
    this.h = h;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        imgIds.setsetVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    h.postDelayed(Worker,1000);

}
```

}

And then the ImageView hide and start the Game.

Comment: Wait, what? Is there a problem here, or are you asking us to write your code for you? If it's the latter, please don't expect help from the community. If it's the former, then please state your problem more specifically? Right now you've just given us a short program specification and what you've written so far, and I'm not entirely sure where anyone else would be able to get with that.

Comment: I'm saying that If anybody could tell me what is my mystake with this code. Because It doesn't work

Comment: You should use a Handler with postDelayed() and a Runnable. Not a thread. background Threads are not allowed to change the UI, i.e. make something visible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183828/splash-image-for-android try this link.take the ans of Yogesh Somani's

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void run() {

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        imgIds.setsetVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(sPlashScreen.this,Next.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     stop()
}   

}
```

Comment: I don't need a Splash Activity. I have a TableLayout with ImageView then when i clicked on menuInflater it'll appear for five second and then hide

Comment: change imgIds.setsetVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) to imgIds.setsetVisibility(View.VISIBLE)